# Color coding within contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I've been trying to breakdown how WYSIWYG editors work, but am having problems figuring it out (and do not need even 5% of that versatility).

My own problem is simple.

Insides a contentEditable div, I have a bunch of text. I want to color code any text that matches a simple pattern. So I may have this text:

> "this is is a text we [can ignore] this earlier one, but anything that [ref=xxxxxx|aaa|bnbb] that fits the ref has to be color coded."

I want any mention that follows the pattern of `[ref=<whatever>]` made slightly smaller/colored.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: The problem isn't regex, it's how to have it colored.

Comment: replace regex capture group matches with <span class="red">$1</span>

Comment: Can't do it while actively editing, only after.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using the fabulous http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ plugin and writing a custom brush for your *syntax*, which shouldn't be too difficult since your syntax coloring requirements are rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a keyup event listener to your contenteditable, you can perform your regex replacements there to add $1 in the contenteditable's innerHTML.

Doing so will reset the caret position, but you can preserve it using [**Rangy**](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

```
function highlight(){
  var selection = rangy.saveSelection();
  contenteditable.innerHTML = contenteditable.innerHTML.replace(/(\[ref=[^\]]*\])([^<])/g, '<span class="ref">$1</span>$2');
  rangy.restoreSelection(selection);
}
```

The regex may not be perfect, but if not, it should get you started.